# How to get the length of a string without calculating the formatting of the text

Tags: python-3.x, string, printing, formatting, string-length

so for example I'm using a library called colored that can format strings for the console.
I'm trying to get the length of that string, but len() calculates the formatting letters too that don't show up in the console... so for example, if I'm setting the string "test" to green it would look like this: "\x1b[38;5;2mtest",
when I print it it just prints test in green so I just want the letter count to show 4.
it doesn't matter what library you are using the format would look the same. is there any way to get the length of a string and ignore it's formatting?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Why don't you count the string "test" first before making it green?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.  I made a function some time ago to do just this.

```py
import re

def len_no_ansi(string):
    return len(re.sub(
        r'[\u001B\u009B][\[\]()#;?]*((([a-zA-Z\d]*(;[-a-zA-Z\d\/#&.:=?%@~_]*)*)?\u0007)|((\d{1,4}(?:;\d{0,4})*)?[\dA-PR-TZcf-ntqry=><~]))', '', string))
```

<sub>Credits: https://github.com/chalk/ansi-regex/blob/0755e661553387cfebcb62378181e9f55b2567ff/index.js</sub>

Comment: Basically, it's a complex regular expression developed by [these people](https://github.com/chalk/ansi-regex/graphs/contributors) that selects *all* ANSI escape codes (which is what those color-making character sequences are), and uses the [Python `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (for regular expressions) to remove the matched text.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = "\x1b[38;5;2mtest"
lenth = len(re.sub("\\x1b\[\d*;\d*;\d*m", "", s))
```

Here is a explenation for the regex: https://regexr.com/630m7